# Configuring tomcat to redirect all aliases to the main domain

Tags: tomcat, http-redirect

I am looking for a tomcat solution for redirecting all aliases (like old names) to the current one (using HTTP redirect)

It would be great if this could be implemented solely in the configuration files.

Note: using a proxy in front of tomcat is not acceptable in this case. I know how to configure if nginx but that's outside the scope of this question. That's only about using only tomcat for doing this.

Example:

- `current.example.com` - current application
- `old.example.com` -> HTTP redirect -> current.example.com

If there is a `*` option it would be even better.